# App rejected in iTunes Connect for PLA 3.3.8

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes

PLATFORM AND VERSION: iOS
Hardware: iPhone
Software: iOS

DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM:

I am developed a call recorder app using VoIP service. It is not an application like other voice recording apps. We are not using iPhone mic to record. Our application records using a VoIP service to record the phone call. When user want to record their call they call our VoIP service number which trigger by taping on Record button.

But when I submitted the app in iTunes Connect they rejected.

The review report is:

"PLA 3.3.8

Your app records the user(s), but still does not have the proper indicators that the app is recording, as required by section 3.3.8 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Specifically, your app records phone conversations, but still does not have an auditory indicator heard by all (i.e., both) parties on the call that the app is recording.

Next Steps

Please revise your app to implement the required means of indicating the recording activity to all parties. Please note that the recording indicator cannot be disabled and your app cannot go blank during recording."

But when phone connects to a number its not possible to show an indicator.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE:
When the app first rejected I add a audio "call will recording" when user tap the record button.
But the app rejected with same issue.

Second time I remove this sound and add a voice "your call is recording" when the call connects to our VoIP number.
But the app rejected with same issue.

What should I do now? Please help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: when your app calls VoIP service for recording, is that happening in a custom user interface designed by you or its like normal calling in iPhone. Can you please show us some photo what is really happening when you call. because you said its not possible to show indicator.

Comment: Thanks  M. K. for your reply. I don't use a custom interface, its normal calling in iPhone. I added two pics. Please help me.

Comment: i know suggesting this will may waste your time but try if you think it might work. Put a confirmation before making call after tap that this call will be recorded. Click proceed if you agree and else don't use your VoIP service and let the user proceed normal calling. This might convince Apple to allow you to use this functionality because then it will be upon the user that its using the users permission.

Comment: But again one more thing you can do. I don't know if this can be customized but you must have seen Google Maps app when uses location it shows a blue ribbon on iPhone. If any option in iOS can do that then it might help that it will show Recording on red background strip while call is going.

Comment: Thanks again M. K. for your help. I will try what you suggested.  I was worked in a voice recorder app earlier and red background strip is not possible actually when calling.

Comment: so try the permission prompt before making the call and recording. might be get approved. Not sure. Lots of apps of mine rejected for other reasons but i solved them but no experience with this one.

Comment: @bhoot4242 i got same issue, please let me know how you solve issue

Comment: hi @MaheshAgrawal can you provide idea to solve this issue

Comment: later i found that its possible to show the red strip. there is a way to show the red strip programmatically. Please do try that and appeal to Apple that now we are showing an indicator and also put a confirmation alert before starting call with recording enabled.

Comment: @bhoot4242 are these issues resolved? can you please help me? I'm facing the same problem and Apple rejected the app for a reason "your app records phone conversations but does not have an auditory indicator heard by all parties on the call that the app is recording"